# Best match Mongodb in complex objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, bigdata, aggregation-framework

I have a database with about 50k records about candidates like the example bellow:

```
[
{
    "_id":{  
       "$oid":"5744eff20ca7832b5c7452321"
    },
    "name":"Candidate 1",
    "characteristics":[  
       {  
          "name":"personal skills",
          "info":[  
             "Great speaker",
             "Very friendly",
             "Born to be a leader"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "name":"education background",
          "info":[  
             "Studied Mechanical Engineering",
             "Best of his class 2001"
          ]
       }
    ]
},
... thousands more objects with same structure
]
```

And given some personal skills I would like to search the best matches for that input:

Example of input:
   ["speaker", "leader"]

Expected output:
   list of candidates (whole object) descenting from the best match.

I basically need to search only the field "personal skills".

What could be a good approach for this problem using MongoDB? Or is there another database that fits better this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query using regex brings us the matching records of  `speaker` and `leader`.

```
db.collection_name.find( 
   { $and : 
      [ 
        {"characteristics.info": /.*speaker.*/}, 
        {"characteristics.info": /.*leader.*/}
      ]
   }
)
```

To have a better performance we can have a [Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) as shown below, but please note that there is only one Text Index allowed per collection

```
db.collection_name.createIndex({"characteristics":"text"});
```

After our Text Index has been created we can see that it is used in our search

Using explain to view the use of Text Index

```
db.collection_name.find({ $and: [{"characteristics.info": /.*speaker.*/}, {"characteristics.info": /.*leader.*/}]}).explain()
```

Mongo shell output with query plan explained

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.a",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "characteristics.info" : {
                                                "$regex" : ".*speaker.*"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "characteristics.info" : {
                                                "$regex" : ".*leader.*"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "characteristics.info" : {
                                                        "$regex" : ".*speaker.*"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "characteristics.info" : {
                                                        "$regex" : ".*leader.*"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "PC369236",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.6.1",
                "gitVersion" : "025d4f4fe61efd1fb6f0005be20cb45a004093d1"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```